# How can I access the base parent of an object in a WPF hierarchy?

Tags: c#, wpf, hierarchy

Deep inside my WPF object **hiearchy** I create a Window object.

However, I want the **owner** of this window object to be the **base Window object**.

I've tried "climbing up the tree" with the following type of code but this approach seems **suboptimal**:

```
(((((((TabGroupPane)((ContentPane) this.Parent).Parent).Parent as
SplitPane).Parent as DocumentContentHost).Parent as 
XamDockManager).Parent as ContentControl).Parent as 
StackPanel).Parent...
```

**How can I access the base Window object?**

I'm thinking of something like this:

*PSEUDO-CODE:*

```
Window baseWindow = this.BaseParent as Window;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach that works for all types is to walk up the logical tree until you find a node of the type required:

```
Window baseWindow = FindLogicalParent<Window>(this);
```

That method doesn't exist in the framework, so here's an implementation:

```
internal static T FindLogicalParent<T>(DependencyObject obj)
   where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parent = obj;
    while (parent != null)
    {
        T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
        if (correctlyTyped != null)
            return correctlyTyped;
        parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

For `Window` specifically, you can use:

```
Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to answer this one:

```
Window baseWindow = Application.Current.Windows[0];
```

Comment: This assumes you only have one window.